# git loop (use git pull, please commit changes to local files)

Tags: git

I appear to be stuck in an odd git loop.

I run:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Config updates"
```

To which I get:

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So I do a git pull:

```
git pull -u origin master
```

And I'm told:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    wp-config.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

So, yea, um, conflicting feedback from git.

What do I do?

I've tried adding that file specifically, i.e. `git add wp-config.php`, no dice. Also tried using the --f flag and all sorts. I just appear to be stuck in this loop.

Comment: Try with 'git commit -am "Config updates"'

Comment: What do you see on `git status` ?  Also, you could specify the current path... `git add .`

Comment: Both of these produce the same result: 'nothing to commit, working directory clean'

Comment: `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: wp-config.php`. You probably get that message because you have an untracked file called `wp-config.php` in your working tree, which, if the `merge` (pull = fetch + merge) were carried out, would be overwritten by a file of the same name coming from the remote repo.

Comment: @Jubobs, I'm fine with that, I have a backup of the file I can replace it with. Is there a way to force it?

Comment: @NathanHornby If you're fine with that, simply remove it from your working tree: `rm wp-config.php`. Then try to pull again.

Comment: Ah of course, that's what I needed, `git rm wp-config.php`. I tried just deleting the file, but naturally that still left 'something' to commit (the removal). This enabled me to pull and replace it manually.

Comment: @NathanHornby So, problem solved? Did poke's answer solve it, or should I write a different anwer? Alternatively, you can also answer yur question.

Comment: "Did poke's answer solve it, or should I write a different anwer?" Bit of both I guess. Poke did recommend removing the file, but it actually needed removing from the working tree. It seems I was stuck in a weird place where the wp-config.php file was in the working tree but not being tracked?

Comment: when "git pull --rebase", it says "error: feeding unmodified ... to diffcore
Cannot pull with rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them", but when "git commit", it says "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours) nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution was relatively simple, although I have a feeling given the other answers that my situation was rather specific (these people clearly understand the inner workings of git more than I).

`git rm wp-config.php`

Was enough to clear the file (without registering a `delete` in the local repo) ready for the pull. So if you end up in a similar situation that's a simple thing to try without needing to rebase or start messing with things too much.

Answer (score 0):

`git add -A` adds all files that are already tracked by Git to the index. So it essentially updates whatever files it knows. As of your currently checked-out version, `wp-config.php` is **not** part of the repository, but just a local file. You can verify that using `git status`.

Now, your remote change you want to pull in *does* know about `wp-config.php`, and the change you want to merge when pulling includes the file. As such, Git warns you that you have a local file that is not tracked by Git yet which would be overwritten by the merge, since the new version would need to track the file.

So you have three options:

1. Either you say the remote version of `wp-config.php` is fine, then you can just delete your local file and perform the merge.
2. Or you add the file in a commit so the merge can happen naturally and the remote version can be merged with your local version.
3. Or you may also decide that `wp-config.php` shouldn’t be tracked at all (since it might be a configuration file that’s specific to the local machine), so it was added by mistake. In that case, you can check out the remote branch separately, remove the file in a new commit, and then perform the merge:

   ```
   git checkout -b original origin/master
   git rm wp-config.php
   git commit -m 'Remove accidentally added wp-config.php'
   git checkout master
   git merge original
   git branch -d original
   ```

Comment: I have a feeling there's more to it than this. Option 1 I've tried, nothing changes, I stay in the same loop (I intended to just replace the file after the merge). 2. As noted above I can't commit the file because it won't let me. 3. This worries me slightly as I'm attempting to pull in development changes into the live environment, I'd worry this would mess something up as it seems quite involved…

Comment: @NathanHornby 1: So you *physically deleted* the file in your working directory? Then the error shouldn’t appear anymore (since there is nothing that can be overwritten). – 2. As *I* noted in my answer, `git add -A` does *not* add the file. So you are not committing it. Check `git status`.

Comment: Yes physically deleted it, the error didn't change (I assume it wanted me to commit the removal of the file). `git rm wp-config.php` then `git pull` did it for me. I just needed to manually replace the wp-config file with the original.

Answer (score 0):

Rebase your branch and then commit your changes

```
git fetch origin
git rebase
git commit -am "Your-Message"
```

Comment: `git rm`'ing the file, pulling, then re-adding it did it for me. I haven't come across `rebase` before though, will look into it!